# $\mathbb Z_n$ modular tables , invertible elements and zero/nonzero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Based on $\mathbb Z_n$, with $n\leq10$, make a guess about which elements in $\mathbb Z_n$ are invertible and which are nonzero divisors. Does your guess imply that every nonzero element is either invertible or a zero divisor?

Attempt: 
Guess for invertible elements:

$\mathbb Z_2$:1

$\mathbb Z_3$: 1,2

$\mathbb Z_4$: 1,3

$\mathbb Z_5$: 1,2,3,4

$\mathbb Z_6$: 1, 5.

and so on.

Guess for nonzero divisors.
Can anyone please help me with the nonzero divisors part?

I know that every nonzero elements must be either invertible or a zero divisors.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at $GCD(x,n)$ to see if a given element, $x$, is invertible. What do you see?

Comment: can you please give an example? How could I guess for the nonzero divisors?

Comment: Note that in the case that we work in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ we have for the element $2$ $GCD(4,2)=2$. Note that $2$ is not invertible, whereas for the element $3$, which is invertible, we have $GCD(4,3)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim**: $a\in \mathbb Z_n$ is invertible if and only if $(a,n)=1$.

Proof: Let $(a,n)=1$. So, there exists $x,y\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ax+ny=1$. Thus, one can see that $ax\equiv 1$ mod n and so $a$ is invertible. Conversely, Assume that $a$ has an inverse i.e. $ab=1$. Hence, $n\,|ab-1$ and there is $x\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ab-1=nx$. It implies that $(a,n)=1$, as desired.